# Custom Angular type is not assignable to type NgIterable

Tags: angular, typescript, types, interface

Since I'm new to Angular I've learned about types and interfaces today. So what I did is I improved my code by coding a custom interface instead of a direct type declaration:

```
@Input()
imageWidgets: ImageWidget;
```

My interface:

```
export interface ImageWidget {
  [index: number]: {
    routerLink: string,
    imageSrc: string,
    title: string
  }
}
```

This is what I pass to the component via the input variable:

```
topics: ImageWidget       = [
  {
    imageSrc  : './assets/images/solutions.jpeg',
    title     : 'Solutions',
    routerLink: '/solutions'
  }
];
```

Now inside the receiving component I'm doing an `ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let imageWidget of imageWidgets"></div>
```

... but since I've introduced my interfaces, I'm getting this error:

> Type ImageWidget is not assignable to type (ImageWidget &
> NgIterable<{routerLink: string, imageSrc: string, title: string}>) |
> undefined | null

I really have no idea why this happens but when I do this here, the error is gone:

```
@Input()
imageWidgets: ImageWidget | NgIterable<any>;
```

I've searched a lot but I'm unable to remote this error message. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are super close! You are looking for this:

```
export interface ImageWidget {
    routerLink: string,
    imageSrc: string,
    title: string
}

@Input()
imageWidgets: ImageWidget[]; // or could do Array<ImageWidget>;
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array

Comment: Oh no I went a bit too deep within my interface but thanks for pointing me the right way. Now the errors are gone.